# Inheritence in viewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an Inheritance Hierarchy like,

```
class Person {
    string name;
    string address;
    PersonType personType; //enum  - value is set in constructors
}  

class Student : Person {
    string department;
}
```

I'm passing this to View as,

```
SchoolViewModel {    
    List<Person> person = new List<Person>()
    {
        new Person(),
        new Student()
    } ; 
}
```

And in the view, I'm iterating the person list and create input fields for each property.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.person.Count; i++)
{
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 ">
        <input asp-for="@Model.person[i].name" aria-label="name" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="@Model.person[i].name" class="text-danger"></span>
        @if (Model.person[i].personType == PersonType.Student)
        {
            <input asp-for="@((Model.person[i] as Student).department)" aria-label="department" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="@(Model.person[i] as Student).department)" class="text-danger"></span>
        }
    </div>
}
```

When I submit, I lose the array index of the department field,

```
person[0].name = "somename"
person[1].name = "studentsname"
department = "somedep"
```

and I can't recreate the object to save. How can I solve this. And after receiving in controller, what is the easiest way to create the list with correct types. Since list is for person and loses child attributes.

Comment: You should go with the newly created class **Student** as it has the department property.

Comment: Actually I'm having few more child classes  and they have unique properties also

Comment: Then make a view model having common properties.

Comment: Hi @iahsp4, what is your version of asp.net core? If i test your code, it will give an error message(`System.InvalidOperationException: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.
`) for line:`asp-for="@((Model.person[i] as Student).department)"`.

Answer (score 0):

I don' t know why do you want to mix two classes in one list, it would be easier to mantain two lists in one view model,  but if I needed it , I would create a viewModel class to do it

```
    List<ViewModel> persons = new List<ViewModel>()
    {
        new ViewModel(PersonType.Person),
        new ViewModel(PersonType.Student){department="dep"}
    };
```

to convert back in a controller action

```
  List<Person> personsConverted = persons.Select(p => p.Clone()).ToList();
```

class

```
class ViewModel : Student 
{
    
    public ViewModel(PersonType personType)
     {
        
        this.personType=personType;
     }
     public Person Clone()
    {
        
        return  personType==PersonType.Person? (Person) MemberwiseClone() 
                                :  (Student) MemberwiseClone();
    }
};
```